# Loading a remote xml page with file_get_contents()

Tags: php, xml, file-get-contents

I have seen some questions similar to this on the internet, none with an answer.

I want to return the source of a remote XML page into a string. The remote XML page, for the purposes of this question, is:

```
http://www.test.com/foo.xml
```

In a regular webbrowser, I can view the page and the source is an XML document. When I use `file_get_contents('http://www.test.com/foo.xml')`, however, it returns a string with the corresponding URL.

Is there to retrieve the XML component? I don't care if it uses file_get_contents or not, just something that will work.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692962/how-to-use-php-to-get-a-webpage-into-a-variable/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to have allow_url_fopen set in your server for this to work.

If you don´t, then you can use this function as a replacement:

```
<?php
function curl_get_file_contents($URL)
    {
        $c = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
        $contents = curl_exec($c);
        curl_close($c);

        if ($contents) return $contents;
            else return FALSE;
    }
?>
```

Borrowed from [here](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php#82255).

Comment: It's not certain to be a replacement - these functions requires that PHP is compiled with cURL enabled. If the fopen-wrappers are disabled the cURL functionality is probably disabled as well. Better to use a fsockopen() function to be on the safe side.

Comment: I've come into lots of hostings having fopen-wrappers disabled but not cURL, so while it's true it's not exactly a replacement, it might be a nice workaround.

Comment: For the return statement I prefer a ternary expression, like this : `return ($contents) ? $contents : false;`

Answer (score 14):

That seems odd. Does file_get_contents() return any valid data for other sites (not only XML)? An URL can only be used as the filename parameter if [the fopen-wrappers](http://se.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) has been enabled (which they are by default).

I'm guessing you're going to process the retrieved XML later on - then you should be able to load it into [SimpleXml](http://php.net/simplexml) directly using the simplexml_load _file().

```
try {
   $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.test.com/foo.xml');
   print_r($xml);
} ...
```

I recommend using SimpleXML for reading XML-files, it's very easy to use.