# Display remote text file on php page

Tags: php

I'm using this code now to display a text file on a php/html page.

```
<?php
foreach (glob("example.txt") as $filename) {
    echo nl2br(file_get_contents($filename));
    echo "<br></br>";
}
?>
```

I'm looking for a way to display the example.txt file from another server with URI.

Something like this: http://address.com/dir/example.txt

Is there a simple way to do this?

(I would use an iframe but it's not possible to style the text without Java or JQuery).

Comment: Make an ajax request to retrieve the file and display the contents on the page.

Comment: that method doesnt work?  `file_get_contents` should grab the file as string from a remote source just fine.

Comment: I did not write this string myself so an example of what this would look like would be super! =)

Comment: You need an answer for the case when you know the file location right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is totally wrong

```
 foreach (glob("example.txt") as $filename) {
                    ^------------------------- searching for a file
```

They can only one `example.txt` file in a folder at a time except you want to get all text files should should be like this in the first place

```
 foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
```

If that is not the case the code would work for both remote and local file

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "on");
$fileName = "example.txt" ; // or http://oursite.com/example.txt 
echo nl2br(file_get_contents($fileName));
echo "<br></br>";
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that mistake. I tried the last code you wrote but that doesn't work with a remote URI for me.

Comment: This works! Thanks! And I take it I can but multiple text files in the same folder now? =)

Answer (score 2):

You could just use

```
file_get_contents('http://address.com/dir/example.txt');
```

Comment: Do I need to allow something in the .htaccess file or do I just add a string of additional code?

Comment: `allow_fopen_url` has to be enabled in the php settings. If you can't change that, take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695296/loading-a-remote-xml-page-with-file-get-contents)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to fetch the content of the file first and then display it.

Another option is to use iframes and set the target of iframe to the desired text file.

Yet another option is to use ajax to fetch the content from client end as suggested in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Check [`fopen()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) / [`fread()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) and your available [transport wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php).

Comment: fopen() look promising. Would I replace the foreach with that?

Comment: Something like `while (!feof($handle)) { echo fgets($handle) . "<br />"; }`

Answer (score 0):

**For normal length text file you can use:**

```
 <?PHP
 $file = fopen("http://www.xyz.com/textfile.txt", "rb");
 $output = fread($file, 8192);
 fclose($file);
 echo($output);
 echo "<br>";
 ?>
```

**For longer files:**

```
 <?PHP
 $file = fopen("http://www.xyz.com/textfile.txt", "rb");
 $output = '';
 while (!feof($file)) {
 $output .= fread($file, 8192);
 }
 fclose($file);
 echo($output);
 echo "<br>";
 ?>
```

It will prevent packet exceed issues in longer files by  concatenating the file together in several groupings using while loop

Comment: This works great! Any idea on how to implement the <br> line braking?

Comment: @Snoffoz ok friend..I have edited the answer for you adding line breaks. Hope this helps :-)

Comment: @Snoffoz Also note that <br> is a single tag so you should use <br> for html sites and <br /> for xhtml.

Comment: Hey! Many thanks for editing. But this doesn't seem to work for me. The text comes up but theres still no line breaks. Tied <br><br> also =(

Comment: @Snooffoz OK I will get it working for you. I think you should add a <div> to echo the file into. Then the line breaks will show up. I will edit the answer

Comment: @Snoffoz I have wrapped the $output in a <div>. It should work now

Comment: Hey thanks for the effort! It already had a separate div. And I cant get it to work now either. Maybe Im missing something. I got a working code from Baba. But I'll be sure to upvote you too!

Comment: @Snoffoz ok i am glad your problem is solved. I will sure correct it too. I cant turn on my PC right now because of blackout.

Comment: Haha, okay. Good luck with the blackout =)

Comment: @Snoffoz :-) ok friend the blackout has receded now. I have checked the coding on my computer, the line breaks are working even without the <div>s. Actually you are not noticing it because there is whitespace at the end of the file. Write a some text bellow the php code and then check it, you will note that linebreaks are working. Even when you remove the echo "<div>"; linebreaks will still work.