# Google Spreadsheet API via PHP

Tags: php, return, spreadsheet, string

i want to read a google spreadsheet over google spreadsheet api via XML.

I try different ways, e.g.

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/WORKSHEET_KEY/private/full");
?>
```

or

```
<?php
simplexml_load_file(URL)
?>
```

but i only give an emtpy string.
the document is public and if i surf on the site directly, it works.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following article: http://arlando.net/blog/connecting-to-google-spreadsheet-api-with-php/

I would also recommend reading this documentation from google API's https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

Comment: The first link doesn't exist anymore. Looks like the site is being updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is more than likely related to the following answered question:

[Loading a remote xml page with file_get_contents()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695296/loading-a-remote-xml-page-with-file-get-contents)

Your server probably doesn't allow opening remote urls with file_get_contents.

The accepted answer on this page shows a workaround with curl