# Ubuntu iptable messing file_get_contents() up

Tags: php, networking, ubuntu

I am setting my ubuntu web server up and I am setting up a firewall on it. All is good except for my one document that has file_get_contents() up. I am just wondering what port i need to unblock for this to work.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/site/videos.php on line 65
```

That is the warning I get from the file. Im sure it's a port issue because if there all unblocked, it works just fine. Any help would be great!

Code for file_get:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/TomSka/uploads'));
```

Comment: Posting your code or `partial (indicating what line 65 is)` would help others to try and help.

Comment: Please post the actual line of code that's failing.

Comment: Have a look at this, may help. See accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695296/loading-a-remote-xml-page-with-file-get-contents - I quote "You need to have `allow_fopen_url` set in your server for this to work."

Comment: It is set. The error only happens when i disable all the ports except for 80 21 22 443

Comment: Ok. Well `ports` are not my `forté`. I've encountered bizarre questions in the past where `.htaccess` played a role, for some strange reason. Sorry I couldn't be of better help.

Comment: Having this same issue..

Answer (score 0):

To change the firewall setting as detailed in the link and it will works. Please refer below document

http://www.radiotope.com/content/safari-and-sonicwall

The setting was "Enforce Host Tag Search with for CFS"

Weirldly it only seems to affect fgets on PHP 5 running on Linux other platforms and other PHP generated HTTP requests are unaffected.