# Save HTML as PDF and email using MPDF

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mpdf

I need to be able to send a PDF version of a PHP page's HTML (with CSS styles intact as some tags are set to `display: none` in a `@media print{}` clause) as an email.

I found [mpdf](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php) which looks relatively easy and seems like a solid solution. The class offers the ability to [email a PDF file](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=373) on the fly. This is great.

My dilemma is as follows:

I want to send `page_1.php`'s contents to `send_email.php` as a url variable to use as the PDF content.

To store this variable I have tried:

```
ob_start(); // at the top of the page

    // THE DYNAMICALLY GENERATED PAGE CONTENT

$html = ob_get_contents(); // I put the page contents into a variable
ob_end_clean();
```

For some reason this does not let the page load in it's entirety. Only a few tags show up. The `ob_get_contents();` and `ob_end_clean();` are sitting before the end `</html>` tag. Is this a potential cause?
I need to use these functions before the end of the page to utilize the variable higher up at the actual 'email link' I created.

I have also tried:

```
$page_url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; // to grab the current url
$html = file_get_contents($page_url); // place contents in a variable
```

For some reason, this does not allow any page on the site to load. All one gets is a spinning wheel in the browser url input.

Even if I can get the page's content into a variable and parse it to `send_email.php`, how would I retain the CSS properties when creating the PDF?

Would a javascript alternative be more viable?

Any help would be outstanding!

Comment: PS: I want to convert the OUTPUT of the php file into PDF

Comment: Would include work for your purposes? But if you're including the whole of page_1.php in sendemail.php, why not just have the code to send the email in page_1.php?

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin, this may solve the issue with CSS style retention. But I would still need the page's content in a variable to use with MPDF..

Comment: I haven't used MPDF, so this is finger in the wind stuff, but would Curl help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692962/how-to-use-php-to-get-a-webpage-into-a-variable

Answer (score 1):

I've had success posting the html to the php file:

```
$html = $_POST['html'];
$head.= '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app/css/app.css" /> ';
$head.= '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app/css/pdf_style.css" /> ';
require_once 'mpdf/mpdf.php';
$mpdf = new mPDF('', 'Letter', 0, '', 12.7, 12.7, 12.7, 12.7, 0, 0);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($head.$html,0);
```